# How to create local helpers to tidy up Vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue component that does a number of complex tasks in `mounted()`.  These tasks include for example, initializing Bootstrap Date Pickers, Time Pickers, and Typeaheads.

At the moment all of this initialization code is in my `mounted()` method.  In order to understand what's going on, the developer has to read through the code comments.

Ideally I would move sections of code to their own methods, and only have method calls in `mounted()`, something such as:

```
mounted () {
  this.helpers.initDatePickers();
  this.helpers.initTimePickers();
  this.helpers.initTypeaheads();
}
```

How can I achieve this?  I realise that I can put them in the `methods` object, but I would prefer to leave that for methods which can be accessed via declarations in templates.

Note that I am not asking how to share helper functions across components (or globally).  I am merely asking how to create local functions in their own space, in order to clean up some longer methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) module which has generic initialization.

```
// DatePickerMixin.js
import whatever from 'specific-date-picker-stuff';

export default {
  methods: {
    initDatePickers() {
      // initialization here
    }
  }
}
```

Then your component just uses the mixin modules.

```
<script>
import DatePickerMixin from './mixins/DatePickerMixin';
import TimePickersMixin from './mixins/TimePickersMixin';

export default {
  mixins: [
    DatePickerMixin,
    TimePickersMixin
  ],
  data() {/* ... */},
  // etc.
}
</script>
```

You could wrap all of these in the same mixin as well.

And if you don't want to always set the mixins, there's [global mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin).

```
import DatePickerMixin from './mixins/DatePickerMixin';

Vue.mixin(DatePickerMixin);
```

> Use global mixins sparsely and carefully, because it affects every
> single Vue instance created, **including third party components.**

Answer (score 1):

As @EmileBergeron said, mixins are a good solution. You can also create plugins, which so happen to encompass mixins as well but much more. They allow you to extend the Vue constructor or add instances/methods directly to the Vue prototype.

[Section on plugins from the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)

```
MyPlugin.install = function (Vue, options) {
  // 1. add global method or property
  Vue.myGlobalMethod = function () {
    // something logic ...
  }

  // 2. add a global asset
  Vue.directive('my-directive', {
    bind (el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) {
      // something logic ...
    }
    ...
  })

  // 3. inject some component options
  Vue.mixin({
    created: function () {
      // something logic ...
    }
    ...
  })

  // 4. add an instance method
  Vue.prototype.$myMethod = function (methodOptions) {
    // something logic ...
  }
}
```

Using your plugin is done by:

```
// calls `MyPlugin.install(Vue)`
Vue.use(MyPlugin)

// pass options to your plugin
Vue.use(MyPlugin, { someOption: true })
```

Here's a small plugin I recycle exposing various string functions in the `pluralize` library:

```
import {plural, singular, camelCase} from 'pluralize'
PluralizePlugin.install = function (Vue, options) {
    Vue.plural = plural
    Vue.singular = singular
    Vue.camelCase = camelCase
}
```

With it you can use `this.singular(str)`, `this.plural(str)`, etc. throughout your components. Pretty simple but convenient.

Comment: I really like plugins, but be careful while extending objects that you don't own, like the `Vue` object.