# Using Global module object within Vue instance methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a global object I can use in Vue but having trouble accessing the methods. I want to use these methods in different components. Also, what's the best approach. I heard about using Mixins but I was thinking about trying a basic javascript object. I hope I'm asking this question the right way.

src/myobject.js

```
 exports.myObj = () => {
  function testMethod() {
   console.log('working');
  }
}
```

src/main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import { store } from './store/store'
import { myObj } from './myobject'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

myObj.testMethod() // NOT WORKING - TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

src/components/App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted: function () {
      myObj.testMethod() // NOT WORKING
  },
  components: {
  }
}
</script>

<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `myobject.js` is a function, which declares a function in its body, which isn't returned. You won't be able to import it.

Comment: I've copy that code doing some research online. Do you know what's the best approach?

Comment: I wrote an answer which shows how to export both named and default exports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a simple ES module that exports **both named functions and a default object**, you can define it like this:

```
export function testMethod() {
  console.log('working');
}

export function otherMethod() {
  console.log('other method');
}

// optionally export a default object
export default { 
  testMethod,
  otherMethod
}
```

Then, it will be possible to import it:

```
import { testMethod } from './myobject';
// or import the default export
import myObj from './myobject';
myObj.testMethod();
```

Now, to [use it in your Vue components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49743285/1218980), there are multiple ways which I already explained in another answer. Using [Vue mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) is one way (beware of global mixins) and [writing a plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) is another way.

In your case, it could be a simple mixin:

```
// my-mixin.js
import { testMethod } from './myobject';

export default {
  mounted() {
    testMethod();
  }
}
```

> Hook functions with the same name are merged into an array so that all of them will be called.

```
<script>
// components/App.vue
import MyMixin from '../my-mixin'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  mixins: [MyMixin],
  mounted() {
    console.log('both this function and the mixin one will be called');
  },
  components: {
  }
}
</script>
```

---

The reason your code doesn't work is because you're exporting a function which does nothing. `testMethod` isn't exposed, it's just declared within the exported function as a local function.

Comment: It's Working now!

Comment: I have a question about doing it this way vs using Mixins?

Comment: @ifelse See my other [answer about mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49743285/1218980).

Comment: Last question hopefully. How to export object with multi methods that I can call ?

Comment: I want to use something like var myObj = { methodOne: function() { //Do this },  methodTwo: function() { //Do that } } and call it like myObj.methodOne